# how to i resolve android asynctask loadfile error?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, bmp

AsyncTask loadfile return for bmp in function
It just android OS 3.12 only error
how do i optimize on asyncTask?

```
            File tileFile = null;

            tileFile = layerTmp.urlMaker_.makeCacheFile(DEFAULT_TILE_CACHE_PATH, tileTmp.tileCoords, (mapView_.getZoomLevel() - mapView_.getAdjustLevelPoint()), layer.layerName_);

            if(tileFile != null) {
                fis = new FileInputStream(tileFile);
            } else {
                throw new Exception("load error");
            }

            out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

            if (isCancelled()) throw new Exception("task cancel");

            boolean isComplete = false;
            isComplete = interruptableStreamCopy(bis, out);

            if (!isComplete) throw new Exception("task cancel");
            out.flush();

            final byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
            out.close();

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;              
            options.inDither = false; //Disable Dithering mode
            options.inPurgeable=true;                   //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
            options.inInputShareable=true;              //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future
            options.inTempStorage=new byte[32 * 1024]; 

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);

            if (bmp  == null) {
                if(tileFile != null)
                    tileFile.delete();

                try {
                    throw new IOException("Image file was not decodable: "+ tileFile);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (isCancelled()) throw new Exception("task cancel");

            if (mapView_.getAdjustLevelPoint() > 0) {
                bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp , bmp.getWidth() << mapView_.getAdjustLevelPoint(), bmp.getHeight() << mapView_.getAdjustLevelPoint(), true);
            }
```

> 10-18 08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889): *****  ** *****  ** ***** 
>   ** *****  ** *****  ** *** 10-18 08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889): Build fingerprint:
>   'lge/express_lgu_kr/express:3.2.1/HTK75D/LG-LU8300-V130.47A6032B:user/release-keys'
>   10-18 08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889): pid: 31983, tid: 31983  >>>
>   kr.co.lgupgis.map <<< 10-18 08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889): signal 11
>   (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 595b7900 10-18
>   08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889):  r0 413784bc  r1 595b7900  r2 00000200 
>   r3 00000000 10-18 08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889):  r4 595b7800  r5
>   413783bc  r6 000000e5  r7 00000200 10-18 08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889):
>   r8 00000d00  r9 00000100  10 00000200  fp 40fa67c8 10-18 08:40:15.095:
>   I/DEBUG(30889):  ip 00000002  sp be91decc  lr ab18d714  pc aff0c9a8 
>   cpsr 20000010 10-18 08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889):  d0 
>   ffd7ffd7ffd7d696  d1  ffd7ffd7ffd7ffd7 10-18 08:40:15.095:
>   I/DEBUG(30889):  d2  ffd7ffd7ffd7ffd7  d3  ffd7ffd7ffd7ffd7 10-18
>   08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889):  d4  ffd7ffd7ffd7ffd7  d5 
>   ffd7ffd7ffd7ffd7 10-18 08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889):  d6 
>   ffd7ffd7ffd7ffd7  d7  ffd7ffd7ffd7ffd7 10-18 08:40:15.095:
>   I/DEBUG(30889):  d8  0000037a3f000000  d9  4433c000000003cf 10-18
>   08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889):  d10 3f7b9adfe3dff7b1  d11
>   3fe53923e0c21ab4 10-18 08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889):  d12
>   3f63fa43864086f2  d13 3ee0ba74ce830ace 10-18 08:40:15.095:
>   I/DEBUG(30889):  d14 3e664d97e3daa951  d15 3df0179b74c46cff 10-18
>   08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889):  d16 ffd7ffd7ffd7ffd7  d17
>   ffd7ffd7ffd7ffd7 10-18 08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889):  d18
>   ffd7ffd7ffd7ffd7  d19 ffd7ffd7ffd7ffd7 10-18 08:40:15.095:
>   I/DEBUG(30889):  d20 ffd7ffd7ffd7ffd7  d21 ffd7ffd7ffd7ffd7 10-18
>   08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889):  d22 ffd7ffd7ffd7ffd7  d23
>   ffd7ffd7ffd7ffd7 10-18 08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889):  d24
>   ce00ff00fa05ea15  d25 ff00ff00ff00de00 10-18 08:40:15.095:
>   I/DEBUG(30889):  d26 c700fb00fa05ea15  d27 f700f700f700d700 10-18
>   08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889):  d28 fffc8934fffc8934  d29
>   fffc8934fffc8934 10-18 08:40:15.095: I/DEBUG(30889):  d30
>   0001000000010000  d31 0001000000010000 10-18 08:40:15.095:
>   I/DEBUG(30889):  scr 20000012 10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):
>
> ## 00  pc 0000c9a8  /system/lib/libc.so 10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):          #01  lr ab18d714  /system/lib/libskia.so
>
> 10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889): libc base address: aff00000 10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889): code around pc: 10-18 08:40:15.175:
>   I/DEBUG(30889): aff0c988 f461428d e25cc001 f400028d f400428d  10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889): aff0c998 f440028d f440428d 1afffff4
>   e3a0c006  10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889): aff0c9a8 f421028d
>   f421428d f461028d f461428d  10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):
>   aff0c9b8 e25cc001 f400028d f400428d f440028d  10-18 08:40:15.175:
>   I/DEBUG(30889): aff0c9c8 f440428d 1afffff5 e212207f 0a00001e  10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889): code around lr: 10-18 08:40:15.175:
>   I/DEBUG(30889): ab18d6f4 e0243e97 e08b5002 e0804004 e1a00005  10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889): ab18d704 e1a01004 e2866001 e1a0200a
>   ebfe7597  10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889): ab18d714 e1560009
>   e0855008 e0844007 1afffff6  10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):
>   ab18d724 e8bd8ff8 e590c004 e92d4ff0 e1a05003  10-18 08:40:15.175:
>   I/DEBUG(30889): ab18d734 e59c6018 e24dd014 e5903008 e1a0e081  10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889): stack: 10-18 08:40:15.175:
>   I/DEBUG(30889):     be91de8c  ab16e9cc  /system/lib/libskia.so 10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91de90  001b6944   10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91de94  001b6944   10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91de98  5959b000   10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91de9c  ab14f218 
>   /system/lib/libskia.so 10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):
>   be91dea0  00000000   10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91dea4 
>   001b6944   10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91dea8  be91e03c 
>   10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91deac  ab165dd4 
>   /system/lib/libskia.so 10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):
>   be91deb0  ab204b80   10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91deb4 
>   ab18d3b8  /system/lib/libskia.so 10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):
>   be91deb8  be91e03c   10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91debc 
>   ab14e4d8  /system/lib/libskia.so 10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):
>   be91dec0  df002777   10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91dec4 
>   e3a070ad   10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91dec8  be91e160 
>   10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889): #00 be91decc  413783bc   10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91ded0  00000100   10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91ded4  001b68f0   10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91ded8  000004cf   10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91dedc  00193bd0   10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91dee0  be91e160   10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91dee4  00000001   10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91dee8  be91e1f8   10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91deec  be91e03c   10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91def0  0000027a   10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91def4  ab171880 
>   /system/lib/libskia.so 10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):
>   be91def8  00000100   10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91defc 
>   be91e03c   10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91df00  00000124 
>   10-18 08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91df04  00000000   10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91df08  000003cf   10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91df0c  be91e03c   10-18
>   08:40:15.175: I/DEBUG(30889):     be91df10  000000c0   10-18
>   08:40:15.355: D/RPC(352): 3000008c:00050000 received CALL. 10-18
>   08:40:15.355: D/libloc(352): Event RPC_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_1HZ_REPORT
>   (client 1) 10-18 08:40:15.355: D/libloc(352):
>   loc_eng_process_loc_event: 4 10-18 08:40:15.355: D/libloc(352):
>   loc_eng_report_nmea: $GSV 10-18 08:40:15.355: D/libloc(352): Event
>   RPC_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_1HZ_REPORT (client 1) 10-18 08:40:15.355:
>   D/libloc(352): loc_eng_process_loc_event: 4 10-18 08:40:15.355:
>   D/libloc(352): loc_eng_report_nmea: $VTG 10-18 08:40:15.355:
>   D/RPC(352): 3000008c:00050000 dispatching RPC call (XID 681125, xdr
>   0x395820) for callback client 3100008c:00050001. 10-18 08:40:15.355:
>   D/RPC(352): 3100008c:327681 sending RPC reply (XID 681125) 10-18
>   08:40:15.355: D/RPC(352): 3000008c:00050000 received CALL. 10-18
>   08:40:15.355: D/RPC(352): 3000008c:00050000 dispatching RPC call (XID
>   681126, xdr 0x395820) for callback client 3100008c:00050001. 10-18
>   08:40:15.355: D/RPC(352): 3100008c:327681 sending RPC reply (XID
>   681126) 10-18 08:40:15.375: D/RPC(352): 3000008c:00050000 received
>   CALL. 10-18 08:40:15.375: D/libloc(352): Event
>   RPC_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_1HZ_REPORT (client 1) 10-18 08:40:15.375:
>   D/libloc(352): loc_eng_process_loc_event: 4 10-18 08:40:15.375:
>   D/libloc(352): loc_eng_report_nmea: $GSA 10-18 08:40:15.375:
>   D/RPC(352): 3000008c:00050000 dispatching RPC call (XID 681127, xdr
>   0x395820) for callback client 3100008c:00050001. 10-18 08:40:15.375:
>   D/RPC(352): 3100008c:327681 sending RPC reply (XID 681127) 10-18
>   08:40:15.395: D/RPC(352): 3000008c:00050000 received CALL. 10-18
>   08:40:15.395: D/libloc(352): Event RPC_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_1HZ_REPORT
>   (client 1) 10-18 08:40:15.395: D/libloc(352):
>   loc_eng_process_loc_event: 4 10-18 08:40:15.395: D/libloc(352):
>   loc_eng_report_nmea: $GGA 10-18 08:40:15.395: D/RPC(352):
>   3000008c:00050000 dispatching RPC call (XID 681128, xdr 0x395820) for
>   callback client 3100008c:00050001. 10-18 08:40:15.415: D/RPC(352):
>   3100008c:327681 sending RPC reply (XID 681128) 10-18 08:40:15.415:
>   D/RPC(352): 3000008c:00050000 received CALL. 10-18 08:40:15.415:
>   D/libloc(352): Event RPC_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_1HZ_REPORT (client 1) 10-18
>   08:40:15.415: D/libloc(352): loc_eng_process_loc_event: 4 10-18
>   08:40:15.415: D/libloc(352): loc_eng_report_nmea: $RMC 10-18
>   08:40:15.415: D/RPC(352): 3000008c:00050000 dispatching RPC call (XID
>   681129, xdr 0x395820) for callback client 3100008c:00050001. 10-18
>   08:40:15.415: D/RPC(352): 3100008c:327681 sending RPC reply (XID
>   681129) 10-18 08:40:15.435: D/RPC(352): 3000008c:00050000 received
>   CALL. 10-18 08:40:15.435: D/libloc(352): Event
>   RPC_LOC_EVENT_SATELLITE_REPORT (client 1) 10-18 08:40:15.435:
>   D/libloc(352): sv count: 11 10-18 08:40:15.435: D/RPC(352):
>   3000008c:00050000 dispatching RPC call (XID 681130, xdr 0x395820) for
>   callback client 3100008c:00050001. 10-18 08:40:15.455: V/libloc(352):
>   sv list:  10-18 08:40:15.455: V/libloc(352):
>     sys prn hlth    proc    eph alm elev    azi snr 10-18 08:40:15.455:
>   V/libloc(352):   0:   1   1   -1  2   0   1   18.000  188.000 0.000 10-18
>   08:40:15.455: V/libloc(352):   1:     1   3   -1  2   0   1   60.000  36.000  0.000
>   10-18 08:40:15.455: V/libloc(352):   2:
>     1   9   -1  2   0   1   16.000  319.000 0.000 10-18 08:40:15.455: V/libloc(352): 
>   3:    1   13  -1  2   0   1   17.000  239.000 0.000 10-18 08:40:15.455:
>   V/libloc(352):   4:   5   10  -1  2   0   1   30.000  329.000 0.000 10-18
>   08:40:15.455: V/libloc(352):   5:     5   2   -1  2   0   1   -1.000  -1.000  0.000
>   10-18 08:40:15.455: V/libloc(352):   6:
>     5   18  -1  2   0   1   19.000  35.000  0.000 10-18 08:40:15.455: V/libloc(352): 
>   7:    5   9   -1  2   0   1   84.000  338.000 0.000 10-18 08:40:15.455:
>   V/libloc(352):   8:   5   16  -1  2   0   1   37.000  146.000 0.000 10-18
>   08:40:15.455: V/libloc(352):   9:     5   20  -1  2   0   1   33.000  233.000 0.000
>   10-18 08:40:15.455: V/libloc(352):   10:
>     5   19  -1  2   0   1   75.000  309.000 0.000 10-18 08:40:15.455: D/libloc(352):
>   loc_eng_process_loc_event: 2 10-18 08:40:15.455:
>   D/GpsLocationProvider(352): reportSvStatus  10-18 08:40:15.455:
>   D/GpsLocationProvider(352): updateStatus 10-18 08:40:15.475:
>   D/RPC(352): 3100008c:327681 sending RPC reply (XID 681130) 10-18
>   08:40:15.595: I/BootReceiver(352): Copying
>   /data/tombstones/tombstone_05 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE) 10-18
>   08:40:15.605: I/DEBUG(30889): detaching 10-18 08:40:15.605:
>   I/DEBUG(30889): debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie! 10-18
>   08:40:15.665: E/JavaBinder(352): Transact on 0x7b8030 in Java object
>   0x4089e728 with code 3 failed 10-18 08:40:15.665:
>   V/GpsLocationProvider(352): getListenerPackageName() packages =
>   [android.uid.system:1000]  uid = [1000] 10-18 08:40:15.665:
>   E/InputDispatcher(352): channel '40a1e410 (server)' ~ Consumer closed
>   input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8 10-18 08:40:15.665:
>   E/InputDispatcher(352): channel '40a1e410 (server)' ~ Channel is
>   unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Comment: Could you reduce down the size of the log to what you suspect is the issue?

Comment: How is this task being called?